# Meteor: multiple languages?

Tags: meteor, internationalization

1) I'm working on a meteor webapp that is a listing of brands. The brands will have both Chinese and English names. I will be making both an Engish and Chinese version of the website. But I will also let an admin add new brands, so all of these English and Chinese names are in MongoDB.

How should I go about making English names display in the English version, and Chinese names display in Chinese version? Would I write a helper to check whether the URL has /eng or /ch?

2) Another questoin is, can I change the path (add /eng or /chi) depending on template variables?

Comment: There are several i18n packages for Meteor, one of them is https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n/

Comment: About your second question, do you use a router? If not, iron-router can do that.

Comment: My question about a package like i8n is that my website has a CMS: Admin can add more "brands", where they will fill out a field "chineseName" and "englishName". I need the "chineseName" to display when the site is in Chinese, and "englishName" to display when the site is in English. But in this package, it basically asks you to pre-define a JSON file with all the translations ahead of time, so how do I apply it to data from Mongo?

Answer (score 2):

There are two packages [tap:i18n](https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n) and [martino:iron-router-i18n](https://atmospherejs.com/martino/iron-router-i18n). They should work together somehow. For routes with different lang parameters (en, cz, ...) use iron-router-i18n. Then tap:i18n should translate your template. I wrote a request for code example update of iron-router-i18n on [Github](https://github.com/yoolab/iron-router-i18n/issues/65). It should be done very soon.

EDIT: I have made an [example](https://github.com/jirikrepl/iron-router-i18n-and-tap-i18n-example) using both above mentioned packages.